# Click Action Throwing Off Affix Plugin

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix, bootstrap-affix

I'm using the bootstrap affix plugin (3.3.7) to affix a set of buttons.  The problem I'm having is that the click event is throwing off the affix plugin.  To test this, I have the following:

```
$("#MainSpySection")
.on("affix.bs.affix", function (e) {
   $.addLog("affix::affix");
})
.on("affixed.bs.affix", function (e) {
   $.addLog("affix::affixed");
})
.on("affix-top.bs.affix", function (e) {
   $.addLog("affix::affix-top");
})
.on("affixed-top.bs.affix", function (e) {
   $.addLog("affix::affixed-top");
});
```

The MainSpySection element is very simple:

```
<div id="MainSpySection" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
    <button type="submit" id="SaveButton" name="Action" value="SAVE" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</div>
```

I did add some custom CSS, but this shouldn't be impacting it:

```
.affix {
     top: 5px;
     -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     background-color: #d4dfed;
     border-color: #c2d2e5;
     padding:5px 20px;
     z-index:1000000
}
```

When I scroll down, this works great, and when I come to the top, the button resets great.  However, every time that I click on anything (element or background), the MainSpySection element switches to scroll mode.  Using my logging example above, I see these log statements:

```
affix::affixed
affix::affix
affix::affixed-top
affix::affix-top
```

Clicking on the document causes it to switch between affix and affix-top style settings, so the affixed element doesn't quite know what to do.  Anybody experience this and know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

After extensive research, I found a bug in the 3.3.7 version of the Affix plugin.  In the "getState" method, there is this line:

```
if (offsetTop != null && this.affixed == 'top') return scrollTop < offsetTop ? 'top' : false
```

and the fix is to simply make the less-than a less-than-or-equal-to:

```
if (offsetTop != null && this.affixed == 'top') return scrollTop <= offsetTop ? 'top' : false
```

That solved the problem.